# Replace values of string before displaying it

Tags: c#

I have a string like this:

```
-Backcheck = 0 Days 2 Hours 15 Minutes\n-Backcheck = 0 Days 1 Hours 13 Minutes
```

before display it I want to change \n for \n Median and remove -Backcheck for nothig so I do:

```
tt.BackcheckToCorrectionsString.Replace("\n", "\n Median ");
tt.BackcheckToCorrectionsString.Replace("-Backcheck", "");
   //Display
  e.Text = $"Mean {tt.BackcheckToCorrectionsString}";
```

But it just return same value, what am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: `Replace` does not alter the string you pass in. It returns the result as a new string.

Comment: If you are doing many replaces in a single string, consider using StringBuilder.Replace.  It does the replaces in place (unlike string.Replace) and does it more efficiently.  The StringBuilder is not immutable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `.Replace()` function returns a new string. It does not modify the current string in place, because strings in .Net are **immutable**. You need this:

```
tt.BackcheckToCorrectionsString = tt.BackcheckToCorrectionsString.
          Replace("\n", "\n Median ").
          Replace("-Backcheck", "");
```

Comment: You can chain the replace statement: `tt.BackcheckToCorrectionsString = tt.BackcheckToCorrectionsString.Replace("\n", "\n Median ").Replace("-Backcheck", "");`

Comment: @J3soon incorporated that into the answer and improved formatting.

Comment: why do you answer an obviously duplicate question? desperate for reputation?

Comment: For users with <100 rep, they tend to get upset when their questions are closed as a dupe. I feel this is part of what has made Stack Overflow feel unwelcoming to so many, so if I can answer quickly, I do.